# Email validation not working in some test cases in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, email-validation

I want to validate the email in iOS.  I've written a category class and here's my code but in some cases like **abc@gmail.com.com** it's not working...

If the user type two times .com or .in continuously it is not detecting it...

I tried with some solutions but that also not working.  That's why am asking here

```
- (BOOL)isValidEmail {
   NSString *emailString = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:   [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

   BOOL isValid = YES;
   BOOL sticterFilter = YES;

   NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
   NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";

   NSString *emailRegex = sticterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
   NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

   if (![emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString]) {
      isValid = NO;
   }

   return isValid;
```

}

Comment: two times `.` is valid i think, some email is `a@b.co.uk` is valid

Comment: ya but @Tj3n now suppose email id like abc@outlook.in.com how to check this one ?

Comment: Is it... but how to identify that .com or .in two times if it came continuously... and to show error.  Is there any way to find these cases...

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya the regex one that OP got is already covered that too, and really , you dont have to be so hardcore OP, your job is need to check the VALID FORMAT, not valid INPUT like `.com.com`, thats user job

Comment: @Tj3n that right its not our job.

Comment: @Sivagami Tj3n is right .

Comment: Yeah... right @Tj3n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

Check it.

```
-(BOOL) isValidEmail:(NSString *)email
    {
       BOOL filter = NO; 
       NSString *stricterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
       NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
       NSString *emailRegex = filter ? stricterString : laxString;
       NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
       return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression works correctly:

```
- (void) checkMail{
   NSString *emailRegex = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}$";
   NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
   if (self.mail.text.length <= 0) {
    //error empty
}else if(![emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.mail.text]){
    //error address inserted...
}else{
    //correct email!
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check following Answer. It may help you.

```
-(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
    {
        BOOL stricterFilter = NO; // Discussion http://blog.logichigh.com/2010/09/02/validating-an-e-mail-address/
        NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
        NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
        NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

        NSArray *firstArray = [checkString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@"]];
        NSString *input = [firstArray objectAtIndex:1];

        NSSet *aSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[input componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]];
        NSString *result = [aSet.allObjects componentsJoinedByString:@"."];

        if ([input isEqualToString:result]) {
            BOOL checkValue = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
            return checkValue;
        }else{

            return FALSE;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function worked for me like a charm:

```
func validateEmailWithString(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex: String = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(email)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
if (![self validateEmailWithString:txtEmail.text])

{
//@"Please Enter a Valid Email Address"];
}




- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)checkString
{
BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```